# State whether the given boundary value problem is homogeneous or nonhomogeneous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'' + 4y = 0$, $y(-1) = 0$, $y(1) = 0$

Solving the differential equation gets me $y = c_{1}\cos(2x) + c_{2}\sin(2x)$.

Using the boundary conditions I get the following:

When $y(-1) = 0$, $c_{1}\cos(-2) + c_{2}\sin(-2) = 0$

When $y(1) = 0$, $c_{1}\cos(2) + c_{2}\sin(2) = 0$

That is as far as I got.

Comment: Hints: Your solution is correct. Now, you have two equations and two unknowns. What can use to solve that? What do you get for $c_1$ and $c_2$ from those ICs? For the definition of homogeneous and non, see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/BoundaryValueProblem.aspx. So, which is it?

Comment: @Amzoti The initial conditions give $y(x) \equiv 0$.

Comment: @FlybyNight: I know that , I wanted the OP to come to that conclusion since he had done all of the work already. Regards

Comment: I knew what homogeneous is. Its just that I could not figure out how to show that the constants were zero or non zero in the nonhomogeneous case. The determinant idea helped me do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the ODE is $y'' + 4y = 0$ then it is homogeneous.

Anything of the following form is homogeneous:

$$a_n(x)y^{(n)}(x) + a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}(x) + \cdots + a_1(x)y'(x) + a_0(x)y(x) = 0$$

where $y^{(k)}(x)$ is short-hand for the $k$-th order derivative, i.e. $\operatorname{d}^k\!y/\operatorname{d}\!x^k$.

Your initial conditions, i.e. $y(\pm 1) = 0$, gives a specific solution of $y(x) \equiv 0$.

Your general solution is correct: $y(x) = a\cos(2x) + b\sin(2x)$.

Your initial conditions give you serious problems though. You have:

\begin{array}{ccc}
a\cos(-2) + b\sin(-2) &=& 0 \\
a\cos(2) + b\sin(2) &=& 0 
\end{array}

Notice that sine is an odd function, meaning $\sin(-2) = -\sin(2)$. Moreover, cosine is an even function, meaning $\cos(-2) = \cos(2)$. The initial conditions become:

\begin{array}{ccc}
a\cos(2) - b\sin(2) &=& 0 \\
a\cos(2) + b\sin(2) &=& 0 
\end{array}

We can re-write these two conditions in matrix notation:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos 2 & -\sin 2 \\ \cos 2 & \sin 2 \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$$

If the determinant of the two-by-two matrix on the left is non-zero then the only solution to this is $a=b=0$. (Non-singular matrices have trivial kernels.) Taking the determinant:

$$(\cos 2)(\sin 2) - (-\sin 2)(\cos 2) = 2(\cos 2)(\sin 2) = \sin 4 \neq 0$$

The last step used the double angle formula: $\sin(2x) \equiv 2\sin x \cos x$. It follows that your initial conditions imply that $a=0$ and $b=0$. Hence, your only solution is

$$y(x) \equiv 0$$